# regex for one letter and three number

Tags: javascript, regex

i tried with this RegEX no solution

`^([a-zA-Z]{1})([0-9]{3})$`

Test Case: Valid

123d

f311

12d3

99A9

Comment: You want 1 letter and 3 numbers, but in any order?

Comment: Does your regex engine allow lookaheads? Try [`^(?=\d*[a-zA-Z]\d*$)(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]?\d){3}[a-zA-Z]?$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/SFuyaG/2).

Comment: \w?\d+\w? You need to show examples that are not valid. BTW what code language?

Comment: Your regex looks fine. What's the context? What tool are you using? If you are getting a positive match, what are the two groupings' values?

Comment: @cmbuckley yes, letter in any case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the combination can be in any order, you may need to list the alternatives explicitly, depending on what your regex flavour supports:

```
^([a-zA-Z]\d{3}|\d[a-zA-Z]\d{2}|\d{2}[a-zA-Z]\d|\d{3}[a-zA-Z])$
```

Comment: u checked for every possible combinations

Comment: There are only 4 places the letter can be :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please check below expression as per your requirement

`(?=(?:.*\d){3})(?=(?:.*[a-zA-Z]){1})^[a-zA-Z\d]*$`

**Breakdown**:

**Look for at least 3 digits:**

`(?=(?:.*\d){3})`

**Look for at least 1 letters:**

`(?=(?:.*[a-zA-Z]){1})`

**Define what is allowed between the start and end:**

`^[a-zA-Z\d]*$`

you can check example [here](https://regex101.com/r/Vd4y5c/3).

Comment: Assuming the question is asking for _exactly_ 1 character and 3 numbers, I would change the quantifier to `{4}` instead of `*`, but this is a great use of lookaheads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookahead to check there's exactly one letter *(case insensitive)* and digits:

```
^(?=\d*[a-z]\d*$).{4}$
```

or 4 characters:

```
^(?=.{4}$)\d*[a-z]\d*$
```

If the lookahead isn't available you can use @cmbuckley pattern, but you can also factorize it. An example in ERE:

```
^([0-9]([0-9]([0-9][a-z]|[a-z][0-9])|[a-z][0-9]{2})|[a-z][0-9]{3})$
```

---

As an aside: never use the quantifier `{1}`, each token without quantifier occurs one time by default.